# Double hash of two TX

Tags: javascript, node.js, bitcoin

I'm looking to double hash two tx, in order to build [merkle tree](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/merkle-tree.asp)

This

```
const bsv = require("bsv");
var tx1 = '3a459eab5f0cf8394a21e04d2ed3b2beeaa59795912e20b9c680e9db74dfb18c';
var tx2 = 'be38f46f0eccba72416aed715851fd07b881ffb7928b7622847314588e06a6b7';

bsv.crypto.Hash.sha256sha256(Buffer.concat(
    [ tx1, tx2 ].map( v => Buffer.from(v, 'hex') )
)).toString('hex');
```

is giving me

```
215f8397a3090a0bc8f4a2e98609a10d55fc7b939fa1ecf9803df20b1ee089a2
```

but it should be

```
13a3595f2610c8e4d727130daade66c772fdec4bd2463d773fd0f85c20ced32d
```

How do I get the correct result?

Comment: `Buffer.concat` expects an array of Buffer instances.

Comment: Perhaps `Buffer` can be skipped when hashing, but tx1,tx2 should be converted to binary as strings are only hex representation.

Comment: yeah, I didn't see the concat :p

Comment: well, I just sha256sha256 using nodejs crypto ... and got what you got - and confirmed it at https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha256.html - by manually hashing the hash

Comment: What makes you think it should be `13a3595f2610c8e4d727130daade66c772fdec4bd2463d773fd0f85c20ced32d `?

Comment: I have a command line test which gives correct hash, https://gist.github.com/mpapec/afd426ff5991078c6c9565fbb87efe93

Comment: Im no perl expert but I can see in that snippet the two hashes get reversed before being concatenated, and then the result hash is reversed again afterwards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [pointed out](https://medium.com/coinmonks/merkle-root-of-a-bitcoin-block-calculated-in-c-8c659a3b3290) you need to convert tx hashes into little endian first before going forward with `concat()` and a double hash.

Since you're using `Buffer` this can effectively be done with `.reverse()`,

```
const bsv = require("bsv");
var tx1 = '3a459eab5f0cf8394a21e04d2ed3b2beeaa59795912e20b9c680e9db74dfb18c';
var tx2 = 'be38f46f0eccba72416aed715851fd07b881ffb7928b7622847314588e06a6b7';

bsv.crypto.Hash.sha256sha256(Buffer.concat(
    [ tx1, tx2 ].map( v => Buffer.from(v, 'hex').reverse() )
)).reverse().toString('hex');
```